# Bug or feature in C# 6? (LINQ to SQL with generic expression is broken.)

Tags: c#, linq-to-sql, roslyn, c#-6.0

LINQ to SQL code is now broken in C# 6. Is it a feature or bug of C# 6?

Let's have a LINQ to SQL mapping:

```
interface IHasId
{
    int Id { get; }
}

[Table(Name = "dbo.Users")]
class User : IHasId
{
    [Column]
    public int Id { get; set; }
}
```

Then an extension method:

```
public static IQueryable<T> GetById<T>(this IQueryable<T> items, int id)
    where T : IHasId
{
    return items.Where(i => i.Id == id);
}
```

The following code works in C# 5:

```
void Main()
{
    using (var db = new DataContext(Connection))
    {
        db.GetTable<User>().GetById(1).SingleOrDefault().Dump();
    }
}
```

However in C# 6, LINQ to SQL fails with:

> NotSupportedException: The mapping of interface member IHasId.Id is not supported.

**UPDATE**:

I have realized that the expression `i.Id` is generated with cast `((IHasId)i).Id` in C# 5, but without in C# 6.

It seems that LINQ to SQL requires the cast (maybe because the `Id` property is taken from the `IHasId` interface not from the `User` class).

(Note: This cast is also lost in C# 5 when `class` constraint is added.)

Any idea why the cast was added in C# 5 but is not in C# 6?

Comment: Related / duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/a/7564154/993547

Comment: Does it help to narrow down `T` to this? `where T : class, IHasId`

Comment: @PatrickHofman Adding `class` breaks also the C# 5.

Comment: Why? With what error / exception?

Comment: I do not know why. Exception is the same: `The mapping of interface member IHasId.Id is not supported.` as in C# 6.

Comment: What happens if you call `Equals` instead of `==` in the extension method?

Comment: @Tamas-SonarSourceTeam Using `object.Equals` works. (I am currently post-processing all queries, replacing `==` with `object.Equals`.)